# Solving an equation using Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just wanted to see if I went about solving this correctly. The problem didn't provide a step so I'm using $.1$:

$$x'(t)=1+t\;\sin(tx)$$

Where $x(0)=0$ at $t=1$

So using the idea that:

$$y_1=y_0+h \bullet F(x_0,y_0)$$

I did the following:

$$y_1=0+.1\left[1+(.1)\sin(1(0))\right]=.1$$

$$y_2=.1+.1\left[1+(.1)\sin(1(.1))\right]=.2$$

I repeated this same formula 6 more times. Did I apply Euler's method correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. A finite difference approximation to $x^{\prime}$ gives:
$$
\frac{y_{n+1}-y_{n}}{h}=1+nh\cdot\sin(nh\cdot y_{n})
$$
where $y_{n}\approx x(nh)$. Moving some terms around,
$$
y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\left(1+nh\cdot\sin(nh\cdot y_{n})\right)h.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
y_{1} & =y_{0}+h\\
y_{2} & =y_{1}+\left(1+h\cdot\sin(hy_{1})\right)h.
\end{align*}
Using $y_{0}=0$ and $h=0.1$, we get
\begin{align*}
y_{1} & =0+0.1=0.1\\
y_{2} & =0.1+\left(1+0.1\cdot\sin(0.1\cdot0.1)\right)\cdot0.1\approx0.2.
\end{align*}
Though your result is the same, your computation is incorrect (in
the first step, you use $t=1$). Maybe this was a typo?

(Also, note that $y_2$ is only approximately equal to $0.2$; not exactly)

Comment: Where am I putting $1$ in the wrong place?  I'm not seeing it?

Comment: Oh I see it.... thanks